# Why I am unable to access this object property in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have this object in Javascript.

```
var callWebPage = function(){
   var url = "/my/uri";
}
callWebPage.prototype.getPage = function(){
   browser.get(url);
};
```

I then create the object using the new operator.

But when I call the getPage method, Javascript doesnt recognize the property url used in the method. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to learn the basics of variables and scope, and what properties are. I'd suggest reviewing some beginner tutorials.

Comment: `url` is a (local) variable, not a property. Have a look at [Object-oriented JavaScript for beginners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

url is local variable inside your callWebPage function. Try this to create 'url' property of your object

```
var callWebPage = function(){
   this.url = "/my/uri";
}
callWebPage.prototype.getPage = function(){
   console.log(this.url)
};
var wb = new callWebPage();
wb.getPage();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `url` outside the function it's declared in because it's a **variable**, not a **property**.

Try this article for an introduction to the concepts:  https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/09/variables-vs-properties-in-javascript/